# Persistent UNC Drive Mount For Service Account

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-server-2019

We're running Windows Server 2019 that I have admin on but I do not have domain admin.  I have a number of Windows services (mainly Apache) that need to have access to a UNC via a mapped drive.  Everything I've found so far requires a desktop login to run a mount script or is obsolete for Windows Server 2019.  e.g. the `psexec -s net use ...` trick no longer survives reboot.

I thought about a filesystem symlink to the UNC but the files need to be available in e.g. X:.  A UNC symlink only connects a local directory to a remote directory.

Does anyone know how to have a UNC mapped drive persistently available for a service account across service restarts and reboots in a modern way?

I wish Drive Manager just let you make a system mount to a UNC.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to create a small physcial partition to house directory symbolic links to the server locations.

```
C:\>mklink /?
Creates a symbolic link.

MKLINK [[/D] | [/H] | [/J]] Link Target

        /D      Creates a directory symbolic link.  Default is a file
                symbolic link.
        /H      Creates a hard link instead of a symbolic link.
        /J      Creates a Directory Junction.
        Link    specifies the new symbolic link name.
        Target  specifies the path (relative or absolute) that the new link
                refers to.
```

```
X:\>mklink /d X:\virtual_dir \\server_name\share\application_directory
```

Answer (score 0):

Mapped drives are for humans. The modern solution for a service account is to use the UNC path and not create a mapped drive.

Comment: That would be a burdensome solution in our case.  We need to redirect the service's working area through something universal like a drive mapping.  It's "legacy" so moving all paths to a central configuration is not going to happen.

Comment: Not all non-human things can consume UNC path, sometimes it`s necessary to take a detour to hide that UNC path.